# "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character" in command line

Tags: python, cmd

So I'm trying to make a little thing like cURL that downloads things:

```
onlinedl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py cfg get-pip.py
```

(It is literally cURL, but I won't release it)

As of right now, this is the onlinedl.bat file:

```
 @echo off
 md "exampleinstall\install" "exampleinstall\src"
 cd exampleinstall/src/
 py src
```

Not much, I've barely started it.

And this is the src.py file:

```
import time
print("installing...")
time.sleep(2)
```

But when I run the onlinedl.bat file, it shows this:

[image: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character]

When I run the src.py file directly from the python shell, it works:

[image: Works like a charm]

I've seen other questions where people put \ in the program, and then stuff after it, which brings them the error, but this one seems different. It's putting "\n" where the new lines are supposed to be. Why is it doing that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: try `python src.py`

Comment: What is the `py` command?

Comment: @venky__ for some reason, python src.py doesn't work, so i did py src.py. it says C:\Users\lilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'src'.

Comment: You should do is to make your batch file more robust, the first thing I notice is that it makes no attempt at determining or defining the current working directory before creating directory trees within it. It then makes no attempt at validating whether those directories were created before trying to use them. Additionally, you could do it a little more efficiently, by using a single line `MD "exampleinstall\install" "exampleinstall\src"`, instead of your lines 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: @Compo edited it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you've followed all of my advice though @LillyM! Notwithstanding the pointless use of `MkDir` over `MD`, why did you replace four lines with two, when I specifically provided you with only one? You've still not defined a current working directory, or performed any check that that directories were in fact created, before using one of them.

Comment: Your latest edit, which should have read `MD "exampleinstall\src" "exampleinstall\src\install"`, following my advice, not `md exampleinstall/src, exampleinstall/src/install`. Don't use lazy code, use doublequotes always as best practice, and there's no need to include the comma, _without using doublequotes, as already advised, commas in directory names will cause you issues anyhow)_. Don't change Windows default path separators, `\ `, to Unix `/` separators.

Comment: Please make your mind up what directories you're creating, so far you've potentially created, `.\exampleinstall`, `.\exampleinstall\src`, `.\exampleinstall\install`, and `.\exampleinstall\src\install`. BTW, your previous incarnation, `md "exampleinstall\src" "exampleinstall\src\install"` is the same as `MD "exampleinstall\src\install"`, which as you can see can be more efficient. You still have 'nix path separators in your `CD` command too!

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the code from another source you need to rewrite in new file. I think it is because of spaces issue. I already faces that issue. it works for me. You can try.